# Ruby Shoes App with two buttons to give a file either Name "A" or Name "B"

Tags: ruby, file, rename, shoes

Lets say I have a file `a.txt` on my C:.

When I press button one in the gui I want to rename `C:\a.txt` to `c:\xyz_a.txt`.

When I press button two in the gui I want to rename the file back to `c:\a.txt`.

How would you do that with ruby shoes? Any hints would be much appriciated.

Comment: Are you facing problem in renaming file using Ruby or handling button clicks in Shoes app?

Comment: I am facing a problem in renaming the file in ruby.

Comment: It states this but how do I add a path: rename(old_name, new_name) → 0

Renames the given file to the new name. Raises a SystemCallError if the file cannot be renamed.

File.rename("afile", "afile.bak")   #=> 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Shoes app that with two buttons that will rename file back and forth.

```
Shoes.app {

    file_orig = "E:/abc.txt"
    file_renamed = "E:/xyz_a.txt"

    stack do 
        @push_1 = button "Rename"
        @push_2 = button "Rename back"
        @note = para ""
    end

    @push_1.click {
        begin
            File.rename(file_orig, file_renamed) 
            @note.replace "File #{file_orig} renamed to #{file_renamed}"
        rescue => e
            @note.replace "Error while renaming #{file_orig} : #{e.message}"
        end
    }
    @push_2.click {
        begin
            File.rename(file_renamed, file_orig)
            @note.replace "File #{file_renamed} renamed BACK to #{file_orig}"
        rescue => e
            @note.replace "Error while renaming #{file_renamed} : #{e.message}"
        end
    }
}
```

Note that my example uses file from `E` drive. To rename files in `C` drive, one typically needs administrator privilege.  You may get error like: `rename': Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (C:/abc.txt, C:/xyz_a.txt) (Errno::EACCES)`.

To give administrator privilege to your Shoes app, you can launch a command line window using `Run as administrator` option (Right-click on command icon in application list and select `Run as administrator`), and from that command window run the shoes app using `shoes app.rb`.

Comment: The problem was indeed permissions on the C:\. So sorry for the stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution.

The folder is C:\Test\, the file is called A.txt and will be renamed to INACTIVE_A.txt with button one and back to A.txt with button two.

```
Shoes.app do
  stack do 
    button "Rename A.txt to INACTIVE_A.txt" do 
      Dir.chdir("C:/Test")
      File.rename("A.txt", "INACTIVE_A.txt")
    end 
    button "Rename INACTIVE_A.txt to A.txt" do 
      Dir.chdir("C:/Test")
      File.rename("INACTIVE_A.txt", "A.txt")
    end  
  end

end
```